# Playframework: Testing with a server example does not compile

Tags: scala, playframework

There is a ["Testing with a server"](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest) example how to test Play framework application with a real HTTP stack.

I tried to compile the example with Play 2.5.2 and Scala 2.11.7 without success. Original example was without imports. Here is the example code with imports I added to get is (almost) compile:

```
package models

import org.scalatestplus.play.{OneServerPerSuite, PlaySpec}
import play.api.cache.EhCacheModule
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
import play.api.routing.sird._
import play.api.routing._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._

object TestExp04 {

}

class ExampleSpec extends PlaySpec with OneServerPerSuite {

  // Override app if you need an Application with other than
  // default parameters.
  implicit override lazy val app =
    new GuiceApplicationBuilder().disable[EhCacheModule].router(Router.from {
      case GET(p"/") => Action { Ok("ok") }
    }).build()

  "test server logic" in {
    val wsClient = app.injector.instanceOf[WSClient]
    val myPublicAddress =  s"localhost:$port"
    val testPaymentGatewayURL = s"http://$myPublicAddress"
    // The test payment gateway requires a callback to this server before it returns a result...
    val callbackURL = s"http://$myPublicAddress/callback"
    // await is from play.api.test.FutureAwaits
    val response = await(wsClient.url(testPaymentGatewayURL).withQueryString("callbackURL" -> callbackURL).get())

    response.status mustBe OK
  }
}
```

And the final compiler error is:

```
[error] /home/js/workspace/example/server/test/models/TestExp04.scala:32: not found: value await
[error]     val response = await(wsClient.url(testPaymentGatewayURL).withQueryString("callbackURL" -> callbackURL).get())
[error]                    ^
```

What is the mysterious `await`? What should I import to get this running?

As a feedback to the example writers I would say that please do not strip the imports away when you prepare the example. Sometimes it may take lot of time to guess the proper combination of imports.

Comment: You can open issues about this specific documentation problem here: https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the answer was earlier in the documentation in place "[Writing functional tests with ScalaTest](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest#Writing-functional-tests-with-ScalaTest)"

where it proposed to import all helpers:

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatestplus.play._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers.{GET => GET_REQUEST, _}
```

The last import here solved the problem. So the necessary imports are:

```
import play.api.test.Helpers.{GET => GET_REQUEST, _}
import org.scalatestplus.play.{OneServerPerSuite, PlaySpec}
import play.api.cache.EhCacheModule
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
import play.api.routing.sird._
import play.api.routing._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
```

Comment: They should update the documentation to include this.  The documentation clearly states "You can access all of Play’s built-in test support and ScalaTest + Play with the following imports:".  Which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could also use,

```
scala.concurrent.Await.result(scala.concurrent.Future<actually it takes super class Awaitable>, 
    scala.concurrent.Duration)
```

which gives you a nice way to timeout the test if it takes longer than specified duration.

Answer (score 0):

Import play.api.test.FutureAwaits.

```
import play.api.test.FutureAwaits._
```

Comment: Adding that caused following error:
object FutureAwaits is not a member of package play.api.test Note: trait FutureAwaits exists, but it has no companion object.